# Parse string to Json - JSON.Parse

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, parsing, razor

String stored in the DB (Json format):

```
{"requiredParam":"value"}
```

### (Razor)Getting a string from the model:

```
<a id="link-test" asp-controller="TestController" asp-action="TestAction">@model.param</a>
```

### Parsing into JSON:

```
<script>
var obj = JSON.Parse(document.getElementById("link-test").innerHTML);
var requiredParam = obj.requiredParam;
</script>
```

using JSfiddle it shows:

```
JSON.Parse("{"required.Param":"value"}")
```

==> not working (the string that i am trying to parse have this format with the double quotes)

==> obj.requiredParam returns undefined

```
JSON.Parse('{"required.Param":"value"}')
```

==> Works

Main purpose is to use the obj.requiredParam
Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you setting `param` in the C#? what does the raw HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use JObject.Parse and GetValue as the following:

```
<a id="demo" asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="Demo">@Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(model.RequiredParam).GetValue("requiredParam")</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSON.Parse('{"'+required.Param+'":"'+value+'"}')
```

Edit: I did not understand the question properly.. Apologies.

How ever you can escape the " using regex.

```
var str = document.getElementById("link-test").innerHTML;
str = str.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
var obj = JSON.Parse(str);
var requiredParam = obj.requiredParam;
```

Comment: requiredParam is returning "Undefined" because the parsing didn't work and that's exactly the issue

Comment: Sorry.. Edited the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

I assume your html looks like this

```
<div id="link-test">{"requiredParam":"value"}</div>
```

So first replace the quotes with `String.replace` and then you can get the json object from it by simply parsing it

```
var elem = document.getElementById("link-test").innerHTML;
var obj = JSON.parse(elem.replace(/"/g, '\"'));
console.log(obj.requiredParam);
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uyf9egxq/